# How populate chart.js with sql data?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, charts, chart.js

I'm using chart.js to generate charts on my page.
However I want these charts to be populated by my SQL database.
I'm able to get my data out of my database, but I won't draw the chart

I got a canvas on my main page called "OmzetChart" , this is where the chart should come.

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'templates/getdata.php',
        success: function (data) {
            lineChartData = data;
            //alert(JSON.stringify(data));

            var ctx = document.getElementById("OmzetChart").getContext("2d");
            var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: lineChartData

            });
       }
    });

</script>
```

The page of GetData.php results in the following (This is what I need, just want it into my chart):

```
[{"dag":"23","0":"23","uur":"13","1":"13","SomOmzet":"23.00","2":"23.00"},{"dag":"23","0":"23","uur":"18","1":"18","SomOmzet":"2.50","2":"2.50"}]

Getdata.php: 
<?php
include ("../PDO.php");


$conn = DatabasePDO::getInstance();
$sql = "SELECT DATEPART(DD, receiptdatetime) as dag ,DATEPART(hh, receiptdatetime) as uur, ISNULL(abs(cast(sum(NetAmount) as decimal (10,2))),0) as SomOmzet FROM ReceiptLine a , Receipt b, ReceiptLineDetail c 
where a.LineType = 200 and a.receiptID = b.receiptid and a.receiptlineID = c.receiptlineID
group by DATEPART(DD, receiptdatetime), DATEPART(hh, receiptdatetime)";
$st = $conn->prepare($sql);
$st->execute();
$list = array();

while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {
    $list[] = $row;

}
$conn = null;

echo json_encode( $list );

?>
```

Comment: Well, you have the ajax tag in there so I assume you know about ajax. Why is there no ajax request to get data in your code?

Comment: @ozan , I tried many many times, however I never get it to work. That's why I ask here

Comment: Have you tried making an ajax call? If so, please share your ajax code. If not you didn't, that's where you should start.

Comment: @ozan , I've updated my post. This code works until the drawing. It just gives me a blank canvas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.json-encode.php) produces a JSON string. You need to `parse` this with [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) before you can use it.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'templates/getdata.php',
    success: function (data) {
        lineChartData = JSON.parse(data); //parse the data into JSON

        var ctx = document.getElementById("OmzetChart").getContext("2d");
        var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: lineChartData
        });
    }
});
```

Also, using [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method's `dataType` parameter, you can leave this parsing to jQuery.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'templates/getdata.php',
    dataType: 'json', //tell jQuery to parse received data as JSON before passing it onto successCallback
    success: function (data) {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("OmzetChart").getContext("2d");
        var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: data //jQuery will parse this since dataType is set to json
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: @Steve, your data is not in the correct format. [Take a look here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-data-structure). `data` should be an object containing the necessary information.